# Gradle error upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Note: This seems to be an issue with the Android plugin. See comments for associated issues.

I get the following gradle error when building the project:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
            at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
            at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
            at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
            ...
```

I will note additionally that I had to set the jdk location manually because if I used the bundled one the gradle daemon would not start, complaining of not being in the expected context (it was expecting the bundled context, instead getting the external context).

This configuration worked (with the bundled jdk) in canary 9.

Comment: Verified issues:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64525949

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64526384

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64526867

Comment: This may help https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

Comment: When you get it posted I'll mark yours I'll just go ahead and do it so the question gets marked as answered.

Comment: For Windows users it is: `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew assemble`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Credit to @Grsmto

As per [this blog post](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html) you need to open a terminal and launch the following commands sequentially:

> **UPDATE**
>
> Now the workaround it's easier, you just need to go to *Build -> Clean Project* and then sync.

**Windows**

`gradlew clean`

`gradlew assemble`

**Linux/Mac**

`./gradlew clean`

`./gradlew assemble`

then sync the project.

Comment: Tried the above, however when I run gradlew clean I am getting the following error: > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta1/gradle-3.0.0-beta1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta1/gradle-3.0.0-beta1.jar

Comment: @MichaelMarsella Make sure you've added `google()` to 

`allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
    }
}`

in your project gradle file.

Comment: @der_Fidelis thanks for that.  I added google() under buildscript { repositories { ...} as outlined by google here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#apply_plugin  and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 14):

From https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html, this is a known issue:  If you have an existing Android Studio project that's using an alpha version of Android plugin 3.0.0 (such as *3.0.0-alpha9*), you may get the following error when you migrate to Android plugin *3.0.0-beta1* and sync your project: *Gradle project refresh failed*. You could solve it by doing the following steps:

**Selecting Build** > **Clean Project** from the menu bar—you need to perform this action only once for each project. You can then sync your project files with Gradle by clicking **Sync Project** from the toolbar.

See the release note for more details. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

Happy coding!

Answer (score 7):

Its a known issue :[As Documented here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html)

Just do this simply (No need to type commands)

- **Build > Clean Project** from the menu bar.
- Then **sync your project** files with Gradle by clicking Sync Project from the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
            at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
```

Read official **[Release Guideline](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html)**

Resolve this issue selecting **`Build > Clean`** Project from the **menu bar**—you need to perform this action only once for each project. You can then [**`sync your project`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sync-files) files with **Gradle** by clicking **`Sync Project from the toolbar`**.

**NOTE**

**`3.0 Beta 1 or 3.0 Beta 2`**

> An early version of a program or application that contains most of the
>   major features, but is not yet complete. Sometimes these versions are
>   released only to a select group of people, or to the general public,
>   for testing and feedback .

Answer (score 0):

Also if none of the 'clean', 'build' etc did not work, then go to Build menu and select "Make Project". It fixed the error for me.

Although it is advisable to perform a clean and build before this.

Answer (score 0):

If `clean` and `sync` doesn't quite work for your Java+Kotlin-mixed project, it's possible that you need to change your Kotlin version to be consistent with the IDE supplied Kotlin version, which as of Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 is `1.1.3-2`. I was using `1.1.4` at the time and I found that I had drop it back down, did my `clean` and `sync` before it all works again, at which point I can move back to `1.1.4`.

Answer (score -1):

Known issue: If you have an existing Android Studio project that's using an alpha version of Android plugin 3.0.0 (such as 3.0.0-alpha9), you may get the following error when you migrate to Android plugin 3.0.0-beta1 and sync your project: Gradle project refresh failed.

Resolve this issue selecting Build > Clean Project from the menu bar—you need to perform this action only once for each project. You can then sync your project files with Gradle by clicking Sync Project from the toolbar.

See the release note for more details. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html