# Gradle sync failed after upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

A project syncing and building OK when on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9. Just started failing the Gradle sync immediately after the upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1!

Using the Android Studio bundled Java 8 without hacks on a Debian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch, stable, up-to-date).

### UPDATE: Solved with Beta 2

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-2.html

Note: additional effort needed on rewriting code to avoid *problematic* Java libs for Android.

---

### UPDATE: First try from Google

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

**Several issues arise** (e.g., errors about signature-polymorphic method without --min-sdk-version >= 26)

These issues were not present on Canary 9!

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26
```

([Google's nonsolution](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html))

---

### Original sync issue

**Same issue on a Windows**

[Gradle error upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597661/gradle-error-upgrading-to-android-studio-3-0-beta-1)

**From Studio**

```
Build: 3.0 Beta 1, AI-171.4243858, 201708032321, 

AI-171.4243858, JRE 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Linux(amd64) v4.9.0-3-amd64 unknown, screens 1920x1080, 1920x1080
```

Gradle '...' project refresh failed

```
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:245)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:184)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:140)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.lambda$get$1(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:55)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:50)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:35)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.getOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy220.getOutputs(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:57)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeVariantImpl.java:60)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.<init>(IdeVariantImpl.java:59)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:88)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:87)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:131)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:214)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597661/gradle-error-upgrading-to-android-studio-3-0-beta-1

Comment: Thanks @der_Fidelis but other issues arise (e.g., errors about signature-polymorphic method without --min-sdk-version >= 26). This issue was not present when on Canary 9.

Comment: if you want to post a new question and link me I'll see if I can help

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to link straight to the known issue fix!

Comment: You're welcome @batjko :-)! I'm still struggling with the issues about building errors demanding API >= 26. I'm using well known libs from Apache, such as, Lucene. Moreover, my pure Java modules are all Java 7 to avoid the Java 8 Android issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597661/gradle-error-upgrading-to-android-studio-3-0-beta-1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**UPDATE: Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3**

With the following list of bug fixes:

[image]

Seems like this issue is already gone. After Updating from 3.0 Beta 2 to 3.0 Beta 3, I don't have to manually clean the project.

**UPDATE: Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2**

From the official [Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-2.html) known issues:

> If you have an existing Android Studio project that's
>   using an alpha version of Android plugin 3.0.0 (such as 3.0.0-alpha9),
>   you may get the following error when you migrate to Android plugin
>   3.0.0-beta1 (or higher) and sync your project: Gradle project refresh failed.

Resolve this issue by selecting **Build > Clean Project** from the menu bar.

[image]

Comment: I've just had this happen as I updated. Is there a particular reason it is happening?

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks for the information. :-)

Comment: If you are updating from an alpha version, e.g 3.0.0-alpha9 you are more likely to get this error. It's a bug in Android Studio. Once you update to a beta e.g 3.0.0-beta1 this issue should not occur. @Cobra47

Answer (score 14):

You can fix this issue by doing this:

```
Build > Clean Project
```

Reference: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

Comment: Cheers, couldn't have been simpler :)

Answer (score 8):

Read here:
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

1. Open the Terminal window by selecting View > Tool Windows > Terminal from the menu bar.
2. Delete all intermediate and cached build files with the following command: gradlew clean.
3. Build your project with the following command: gradlew assemble.
4. Sync your project files with Gradle by clicking Sync Project from the toolbar.

Or as I did, open the tab "Gradle" and run "clean" and then "assemble"
like this:

Go to your right at Android Studio, open the tab "gradle", then in ":app"/"Tasks"/"build" you will see "clean", "assemble" and other tasks.

Run first clean and then assemble, you may get an error but it still works and finally rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks @Devofure but that didn't fully work for me. I've edited my question to explain what went wrong!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [solution offered by Google](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html):

Resolve this issue selecting *Build* > *Clean Project* from the menu bar. You need to perform this action only once for each project. You can then sync your project files with Gradle by clicking *Sync Project* from the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Following solutions didn't work for me :

1. Pressing that try again button again and again
2. Using offline and online gradle changes
3. Cleaning, syncing or rebuilding.

Solution:

After all these I just visited ~/.gradle folder, it contains a single folder named wrapper, just rename it to anything else i.e. wrapper123. That's it problem solved !!!! Press build and it will start syncing and building the project

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me since upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.1 from Android Studio 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2, and I found that on top of the `clean` and `sync` proposed here, for my project which was Java-Kotlin-mixed code base, I had to drop my Kotlin version to `1.1.3-2`, which is the IDE bundled version, `clean` & `sync` then works, and then I can bring the Kotlin version back to `1.1.4` which is latest at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

recquired online for until fix the error (fixing the gradle error.after successfully fixed the errror.you can work in offline.)
**1.download latest gradle from ->https://gradle.org/releases**
2.**after downloading the zip files,it extract all the files into a folder** (for good work:-name the folder 'gradle4',place the samelocal disc where your android studio installed eg-you installed android studio in local disc :c if place the 'gradle4' in local disc c)
3.**android studio->file menu->settings->build,Excecution,Deployment->Gradle**
4.**check-use local gradle distribution**
5.**give gradle folder path into the gradle home option**[Screen shot of gradle setting step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnZfL.jpg)

6.**Enable embedded Maven Repository**
[Screen shot of Enable Maven Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dN8Z.png)

**click ->apply**
**Build menu->clean project**
-problem solved-