# Error while integrating Realm in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I am trying to integrate Realm 4.3.1 but I am getting weird error, which I am not able to resolve. I have referred [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest), I am using

> Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4,
>
> Gradle Version 4.1
>
> Android Plugin Version 3.0.0-alpha4

Here is an error

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:245)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:140)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.lambda$get$1(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:54)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:49)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:34)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.getOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy187.getOutputs(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeVariantImpl.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.<init>(IdeVariantImpl.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:87)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:211)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Application gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.###.###"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.17"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'

    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:4.3.1'

}
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

> Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598532/3321991

Comment: Yeah Clean > Build worked but now I am getting `Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: io.realm:realm-android:4.3.1`

Comment: does it work if you add `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` underneath `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`?

Comment: @petey Yeah that is what I needed to change and also need to remove gradle dependency from app module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:4.3.1'` from you application level `build.gradle` file and apply `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` just below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. Your application level `build.geadle` will look like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.###.###"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.17"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
}
```

Comment: Yes I just got the same solution. Thank you very much for your efforts although.

Answer (score 0):

With the realm 4.3 you need to have gradle 4.1 in your gradle-wrapper.properties like that :

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

I had to update my Android Studio to 3.0.1 in order to have it. That was the reason why I couldnt import realm. ^^